# JQuery POST aborted after page redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, asynchronous

I have JQuery ajax POST operation which saves some data to a database. The operation takes about less than 20 milliseconds. This piece of javascript is embedded inside a .NET Web Forms application (out of my control). This .NET application triggers my POST inside a submit button and redirects to a another page. Now for the following browsers the POST is never executed:

- FF on Windows
- Safari on MAC
- Chrome on MAC

IE works fine and even Chrome on Windows.

So I did some tests and tried to mimic the .NET Web Forms website which I luckily could reproduce by adding 'window.location = "go to another site"' directly after my save action. Here is my (stripped) code:

```
//BUTTON
$('#someSaveButton').click(function () {          
    GlobalObject.save();
});

// GLOBAL OBJECT CONTAINING ALL MY ACTIONS (delete, check, save, get)
var GlobalObject = (function () {
    return {
        save: function () {
            ...
            someMode.save(); //NOTE: Depending on an url parameter different save methods are supported
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"; //MIMIC-ING REQUEST ABORTING
        }
    };
})();

//EVENTUALLY THE SAVE:
function save() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: ...,
        data: ...,
    contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (response) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

This above reproduces the same POST-aborting behaviour. NOTE: the browser debugger reaches the $.ajax statement but never returns into 'success' or 'error'.

SOUTION I FINALLY FOUND:
I added 'async : false,' to the ajax call and everything seems to work fine!

Now I want to be sure if this is a correct solution because when I read on the JQuery site:

As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

I get a feeling the 'async: false' is maybe not a good solution. Is my Javascript construction OK? My background is C# and I am still learning/struggling on how to correctly embed/use functions inside javascript class definitions. So maybe my errors are related to a wrong construction of my functions (and the javascript garbage collector is cleaning things up or something).

Comment: Now after 1 week production testing setting async to false was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of async: false is justified and correct in this instance.

The deprecation note refers to setting callback handlers on the jqXHR object, but you're already supplying them through the options object anyway.

Using async: false in this situation would not be incorrect, since the page is closing anyway and the user wouldn't expect it to be responsive, so the execution blocking goes mostly unnoticed (aside from the fact that 20 milliseconds are near inconceivable).

From the information provided, I don't see a cleaner solution than this.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this. I looked on the web for jqXHR but could not relate it to my situation.

Comment: @Stackbever It's the return value of the `$.ajax()` function. See the types page of jQuery for more information: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR

Comment: Thanks to your link and re-re-reading my post I finally understand!

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, instead of settings `async` as false, you can do the redirect (`window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";`) **within** the `success` callback of the `$.ajax` call (and leave `async: true`):

```
//BUTTON
$('#someSaveButton').click(function () {          
    GlobalObject.save();
});

// GLOBAL OBJECT CONTAINING ALL MY ACTIONS (delete, check, save, get)
var GlobalObject = (function () {
    return {
        save: function () {
            // ...
            someMode.save(); //NOTE: Depending on an url parameter different save methods are supported
        }
    };
})();

//EVENTUALLY THE SAVE:
function save() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: ...,
        data: ...,
    contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (response) {
            // do stuff
            // more stuff
            // ... redirect when completed stuff
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"; //MIMIC-ING REQUEST ABORTING
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my question, but the window.location.href was just testing code and is not part of the production code. The .NET code is doing something like Response.Redirect so I wanted it to mimic it using a javascript redirect which results in the same error.

Comment: which part of code does the `Response.Redirect`? server side code? if so- the browser client WILL NOT be redirected (but the AJAX request context will be).

if you wish to redirect after a success ajax call, do it on client side, never on server side.

Comment: The situation is: 1. .NET Web Forms has a form submit button, 2. Client side this submit button calls my save, 3. It then goes to the server to post its own data, 4. It shows up a new page to the user (compare it to a wizzard with a 'next' button). Because this is all out of my control I came up with the 'window.location.href' in order to simulate this.

Comment: not sure i understood exactly what you need. anyway- calling the `location.href` or other code WITHIN the `success` ajax callback will do what you wish, and the ajax call will not be aborted.

Comment: Maybe if setting 'async to false' still fails on our production server, I can use your suggestion. I am thinking of the web forms site gives me the 'post to this page after a successfull save'. As an extra url parameter or something.

Comment: again, you can't redirect the browser client with an ajax call. you CAN return the 'redirect_url' or similar and do a `location.href=`...